# Combining CSS Grid with transform

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-grid

Is there any way to combine CSS Grid with transforms to move divs around a grid layout?

For example, if the user clicks Box B (it would expand to occupy the space currently held by itself and boxes C and F) , how could I use transforms to slide C and F out of the newly occupied space and into space currently unoccupied within the grid?

[image: Sample grid layout]

Code as follows:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 18% 20px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 30% 20px);
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The CSS Grid spec provides a multitude of properties and methods for adjusting your layout.

To adjust the size and placement of any grid item, you can use *defined placement* (as opposed to *auto placement*).

Here are some examples:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 75px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 75px);
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-auto-columns: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.a:hover {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  background-color: orange;
}

.b:hover {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.c:hover~.box {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  background-color: pink;
}

.h:hover {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  background-color: green;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A<br>hover</div>
  <div class="box b">B<br>hover</div>
  <div class="box c">C<br>hover</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H<br>hover</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8ysp0te/)

---

With regard to this part of your question:

> How could I use transforms to slide C and F out of the newly occupied space and into space currently unoccupied within the grid?

The Grid spec actually provides a method for accomplishing this exact behavior.

With `grid-auto-flow: dense`, the Grid auto-placement algorithm will look to fill unoccupied cells with items that fit.

> [**7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
>
> Grid items that aren’t explicitly placed are automatically placed into
>   an unoccupied space in the grid container by the auto-placement
>   algorithm.
>
> `grid-auto-flow` controls how the auto-placement algorithm works,
>   specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed into the grid.
>
> ***`dense`***
>
> If specified, the auto-placement algorithm uses a “dense” packing
>   algorithm, which attempts to fill in holes earlier in the grid if
>   smaller items come up later. This may cause items to appear
>   out-of-order, when doing so would fill in holes left by larger items.

In the example below, `grid-auto-flow: dense` is activated on hover.

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-wrapper:hover {
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.a, .h {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.b, .e {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.f {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-wrapper:hover .g,
.grid-wrapper:hover .h {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8ysp0te/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Animating that though appears to be beyond the scope of CSS Grid at the moment, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to apply transitions to my examples for smoother effects. Didn't work on any grid properties I tried. Will have to study that more closely another time. Cheers!

Comment: Apparently it's browser issues. Animations are supposed to be available, but they're not. https://codepen.io/matuzo/post/animating-css-grid-layout-properties

Comment: Right, I saw that in the spec. But the grid item properties are apparently not animatable ("discrete"), and are not listed in that article.